# What's the relationship between connection and transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

First I create two transactions with the same connection.

Whether the other one will roll back if I roll back one of them?

I want to know the right result and why.

Comment: You can think of a transaction as an atomic action that the database commits. Transactions have nothing to do with a connection (apart that they require one...)

Answer (score 0):

A single ROLLBACK (without a save point or transaction name) will roll back all uncommitted transactions.  The relevant excerpt from the SQL Server Books Online (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx):

> When nesting transactions, this same statement rolls back all inner
>   transactions to the outermost BEGIN TRANSACTION statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as multiple transactions per connection. There can only be zero or one. Opening a transaction a 2nd time only increments `@@TRANCOUNT`.

A `ROLLBACK` rolls back the transaction and sets `@@TRANCOUNT` to zero.

Use savepoints if you want partial rollback.